# Finding an ID not in another column

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I'm working on a little SQL exercise, and am scratching my head an this problem.

I am trying to find all the Employees to whom no other employee reports to.
This is what the `employees` table looks like:

```
   EmployeeId   LastName    FirstName   Title                 ReportsTo
             1  Adams       Andrew      General Manager       null
             2  Edwards     Nancy       Sales Manager         1
             3  Peacock     Jane        Sales Support Agent   2
             4  Park        Margaret    Sales Support Agent   2
             5  Johnson     Steve       Sales Support Agent   2
             6  Mitchell    Michael     IT Manager            1
             7  King        Robert      IT Staff              6
             8  Callahan    Laura       IT Staff              6
```

I thought a straightforward one of these queries would do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM employees
Where EmployeeId not in (select ReportsTo from employees)


SELECT *
FROM employees
Where EmployeeId not in (ReportsTo)
```

But those return the following results, which isn't what I'm looking for:

```
EmployeeId  LastName    FirstName   Title                ReportsTo
         2  Edwards     Nancy       Sales Manager        1
         3  Peacock     Jane        Sales Support Agent  2
         4  Park        Margaret    Sales Support Agent  2
         5  Johnson     Steve       Sales Support Agent  2
         6  Mitchell    Michael     IT Manager           1
         7  King        Robert      IT Staff             6
         8  Callahan    Laura       IT Staff             6
```

Why is `NOT IN` returning items that are definitely in that column? How would I go about returning items not in `ReportsTo` if I am using `NOT IN` incorrectly?

Comment: The first query is supposed to return an empty result set. Try `NOT EXISTS` instead.

Comment: Specify the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your 1st query is that you use `NOT IN` with a list that contains a `NULL` value.
So a comparison of an `EmployeeId` like say 5:

```
5 NOT IN (null, 1, 2, 6)
```

will return `NULL`, because any comparison to `NULL` returns `NULL` and that `EmployeeId` will not be included in the results.
Change to:

```
SELECT *
FROM employees
Where EmployeeId not in (
  select ReportsTo 
  from employees 
  where ReportsTo is not null
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8v1WtxcYknvnykL4fsNsfL/0).
Results:

```
| EmployeeId | LastName | FirstName | Title               | ReportsTo |
| ---------- | -------- | --------- | ------------------- | --------- |
| 3          | Peacock  | Jane      | Sales Support Agent | 2         |
| 4          | Park     | Margaret  | Sales Support Agent | 2         |
| 5          | Johnson  | Steve     | Sales Support Agent | 2         |
| 7          | King     | Robert    | IT Staff            | 6         |
| 8          | Callahan | Laura     | IT Staff            | 6         |
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `not exists` with a correlated subquery (as commented by jarlh):

```
select *
from employees e
where not exists (
    select 1
    from employees e1 
    where e1.ReportsTo = e.EmployeeId   
)
```

Comment: @ksm . . . `not exists` is the best practice when using a subquery; `not in` has unexpected behavior with `NULL` values.  Don't use it.  Don't worry about it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff (and GBM) Ah! Makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use the below query--

```
select * from employees emp where employeeID not in (select ReportsTo from employee)
```

Comment: Thats...almost the exact query in my post?